# Scope of active substitutions in the applied $\pi$-calculus

Tags: pi-calculus

As I have seen a few questions on calculi floating around, I figure this is the right place to ask. Suppose we have an extended process $P \equiv \nu \tilde{n}.\left( \{M/x\} \mid N \right)$ where $\{M/x\}$ denotes an active substitutions and $M$ and $N$ are some terms.

The question i ask myself is, whether we generally substitute $x$ for $M$ in $N$ if $x \in N$, or whether it depends on if $x \in \tilde{n}$ such that it is bound by $\nu \tilde{n}$. In other words, are processes computing in parallel in scope of active substitutions, and if yes, on what conditions?

Despite skimming through several papers, i did not manage to get a clear cut answer.

Comment: Can you define (or give a reference to the definition of) "active substitution"?

Comment: Sure. Ben Smyth wrote an introductory paper on the applied $\pi$-calculus which includes the definition of active substitutions. Simply [click.](http://www.bensmyth.com/files/Smyth10-applied-pi-calculus.pdf)

Comment: I skimmed through the definitions, I think it is pretty clear that {M/x} | N is structurally equivalent to {M/x} | N' where N' is N in which every free occurrence of x is replaced by M.  This behavior is the expected one and I did not see anything in the text contradicting it.  In particular, it does not matter whether x is bound by the restriction or not.  So, if I correctly understood your question, the answer is yes, the scope of an active substitution {M/x} extends to every parallel process which "knows" x (e.g., in ($\nu$x.{M/x}) | P, the process P is out of scope).

Comment: What is the variable $x_1$?

Comment: I edited the post and forgot to remove the index. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding scope management in $\pi$-calculi is to look at the **structural congruence** $P \equiv Q$ and at the notions of **free name** $\newcommand{\FN}[1]{\text{fn}(#1)}\FN{P}$ and **free variable** $\newcommand{\FV}[1]{\text{fv}(#1)}\FV{P}$. The great novelty that distinguishes $\pi$-calculi from its predecessors is the ability to **extrude scope**. It is guided by the following law.

$$
   P \ |\ (\nu x)Q \ \equiv\ (\nu x)(P\ |\ Q) \qquad \text{if $x \notin \FN{P} \cup \FV{P}$}.
$$

This rule is also at the heart of the applied $\pi$-calculus, otherwise it would not be a $\pi$-calculus. In order to understand the scope of active substitution in the applied $\pi$-calculus, we need to understand the free names and variables of an active substitution. This is defined in Section 2.1 of "[Mobile values, new names, and secure communication](http://crysys.hu/members/tvthong/pispi/applied.pdf)", the paper that introduces the applied $\pi$-calculus:

- $\FV{\{M/x\}} = \FV{M} \cup \{x\}$.
- $\FN{\{M/x\}} = \FN{M}$.

The full definition of structural congruence in applied $\pi$ is a bit more elaborate because the calculus parameterises the definition of structural congruence with application-specific equations that define cryptographic primitives, e.g. $\text{decode}_k(\text{encode}_k(msg)) \equiv msg$. In other words, the algebraic laws that give the (formal) cryptography are embedded in the structural congruence. In addition, active substitution itself has associated structural congruence laws:

- $(\nu x)\{M/x\} \equiv 0$.
- $\{M/x\} | P \equiv \{M/x\} | P\{M/x\}$.
- $\{M/x\} \equiv \{N/x\}$ whenever the equation $M = N$ holds in the paramterisation.

None of these additional structural congruences does anything 'unusual' with extrusion, so, as Damiano says, whether $M$ substitutes for $x$ in $N$ has nothing to do with restrictions 'on the outside' in $(\nu \vec{n})(\{M/x\} | N)$, but only with $x$ occurring in $N$ or not.